# Insert records in many to many not working with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to insert 2 new records in their tables and also to create the relation many to many.

There are a lot of questions with this topic, I tried many of the answers and now I have no idea why my code is not working.

Please help me!

This is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyContext db = new MyContext();

        var st1 = new Student() { Name = "Joe" };
        var c1 = new Course() { Name = "Math" };

        db.Courses.Attach(c1);
        st1.Courses.Add(c1);
        db.Students.Add(st1);         

        db.SaveChanges();            
    }       
}
public class Student
{
 public Student()
    {
        Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Courses)
            .WithMany(d => d.Students)
            .Map(t =>
            {
                t.MapLeftKey("studentId");
                t.MapRightKey("courseid");
                t.ToTable("StudentCourse");
            });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

**Edit: Like sugested, I initialized the Courses:**

```
 public Student()
    {
        Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }
```

and now I get this error on db.SaveChanges();

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Your `st1` is not an EF wrapper - it is just the object of type `Student`, and `Student` class doesn't initialize its `Courses` collection.

Comment: How can I make it work?

Comment: Initilialize the `Courses` collection with some `new List<Student>()` or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're apparently trying to add a new `Student` to the database and associate it to an *existing* `Course`. The problem is that you attach a new `Course` entity to the context without a proper primary key.

It certainly is a good idea to use a so-called *stub entity* here, because it saves a roundtrip to the database to fetch an existing `Course`, but the primary key is required for EF to create a correct association record. It's  even the only property you need to set in this `Course` stub:

```
var st1 = new Student() { Name = "Joe" };
var c1 = new Course() { CourseId = 123 };

db.Courses.Attach(c1);
st1.Courses.Add(c1);
db.Students.Add(st1);
```

If you want to add a new course and a new student, you should `Add` both of them:

```
db.Courses.Add(c1);
st1.Courses.Add(c1);
db.Students.Add(st1);
```

Comment: Both values (st1, c1) are new values, does not exist in database, and Yes, I was trying to insert in on trip this 2 new values in all 3 tables. Is it posible?

Comment: Now is working :), i had tried a lot of combination, only this on no :)

Comment: @Arnold can you please edit your answer with the comment, because I mark your answer as accepted. Thank you

Comment: I already did. I just show both possibilities to make the answer more applicable for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't initialising the `ICollection` object in either class.

```
public class Student
{
    private Student()
    {
        Courses = new List<Course>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

Try changing your modelBuilder code to the following

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany<Course>(s => s.Courses)
            .WithMany(c => c.Students)
            .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("StudentRefId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("CourseRefId");
                        cs.ToTable("StudentCourse");
                    });
```

Code sample taken directly from:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I got the same error 'new List<Course>();' 0 which I posted in the edit

Comment: I dropped the database, and recreated with your suggested changes in configuration, and gor the same error, like the one posted in my edit.